# Slows down the CYCLES engine in blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine

when you select the cycles render engine and press f12, the computer starts to slow down very much. The manipulations with changing the CPU and GPU will not help.

Other engines do not have this Corona, v-ray, eve.

a computer:
r9 5900x
1060(3gb)
32gb

Comment: What is your question? - Any complex scene will slow down a machine when rendering.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Renders are designed to utilize as much CPU power as possible - this will often lead to 100% CPU usage, which will naturally cause other processes on the PC to run more slowly (in general) until the render is complete.